# have a custom serach in my html ?that search in my html as ctrl + F

Tags: html, html-parsing

I want to have a search box in my **HTML** page  that work exactly as **Ctrl + F** in browsers.
i guess that i must do something with JavaScript and parsing ... any idea?

Comment: Why doesn't ctrl-f do what you want?

Comment: He is trying to override the default browser CTRL+F to get some valuable informations about search and pass it by AJAX to his server ;). Users sometimes CTRL+F passwords for example... Please, do not answer this question ;).

Comment: I have a person list shown in my page . i want to give this opportunity for user to search in this list . i don't want to use some particular code ..